# Exclude native functions, JNI methods, lib from ProGuard with Android using Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, android, eclipse, obfuscation, android-proguard

Getting following error when I try to exclude native call & JNI method in the ProGuard.

Basically I want to NOT to obfuscate "createCustomWidget()" in native code and its callback to my activity through JNI, and want to use createCustomWidget() from native code and its callback to my activity through JNI.  Thanks in advance.

Here are the errors:

```
02-01 14:48:51.502: E/PersonaManagerService(973): returning null in  getPersonasForUser
02-01 14:48:51.512: W/dalvikvm(22357): Exception thrown (Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;) while throwing internal exception (Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;)
02-01 14:48:51.512: W/dalvikvm(22357): Exception thrown (Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;) while throwing internal exception (Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;)
02-01 14:48:51.512: W/dalvikvm(22357): Exception thrown (Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;) while throwing internal exception (Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;)
02-01 14:48:51.512: W/dalvikvm(22357): Exception thrown (Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;) while throwing internal exception (Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;)
02-01 14:48:51.512: W/dalvikvm(22357): Exception thrown (Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;) while throwing internal exception (Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;)
02-01 14:48:51.512: A/libc(22357): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 22991 (AsyncTask #4)
02-01 14:48:51.512: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(1248): sendKeyguardVisibilityChanged(true)
02-01 14:48:51.512: I/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(1248): visibility is same
....
02-01 14:48:51.682: I/DEBUG(319):     scr 20000012
02-01 14:48:51.682: I/DEBUG(319): backtrace:
02-01 14:48:51.682: I/DEBUG(319):     #00  pc 00070346  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmGetVirtualizedMethod(ClassObject const*, Method const*)+1)

02-01 14:48:51.682: I/DEBUG(319):     #01  pc 00050bf7  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-01 14:48:51.682: I/DEBUG(319):     #02  pc 0003aa11  /data/app-lib/com.ak.customwidget-5/libcustomwidget.so (_JNIEnv::CallObjectMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+18)

02-01 14:48:51.682: I/DEBUG(319):     #03  pc 0003ab0d  /data/app-lib/com.ak.customwidget-5/libcustomwidget.so (Java_com_ak_customwidget_customwidget_CustomWidget_createCustomWidget+164)
02-01 14:48:51.682: I/DEBUG(319): stack:
02-01 14:48:51.682: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba939c8  7898a1c8  /data/app-lib/com.ak.customwidget-5/libcustomwidget.so

02-01 14:48:51.682: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba939cc  00000000  
02-01 14:48:51.682: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba939d0  00000000  
....
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba939f8  7ba93a5c  [stack:22991]
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba939fc  417a11ef  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDecodeIndirectRef(Thread*, _jobject*)+34)

02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a00  78510df0  
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a04  1e000005  
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):     #00  7ba93a08  7348d1a0  
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a0c  444939c8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)

02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a10  7ba93a5c  [stack:22991]
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a14  417a3bfb  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):     #01  7ba93a18  00000000  
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a1c  417a01b1  /system/lib/libdvm.so

02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a20  4432f5b8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a24  78510df0  
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a28  76c9ad82  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.ak.customwidget-5.apk@classes.dex

02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a2c  7ba93a70  [stack:22991]
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a30  78510e98  
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a34  417a3bd5  /system/lib/libdvm.so

02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a38  1e000005  
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a3c  00000000  
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a40  7ba93a70  [stack:22991]
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a44  7889fa13  /data/app-lib/com.ak.customwidget-5/libcustomwidget.so (_JNIEnv::CallObjectMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+20)

02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):     #02  7ba93a48  7348d1a0  
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a4c  7ba93a5c  [stack:22991]
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a50  7348d1a0  
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a54  7889fb11  /data/app-lib/com.ak.customwidget-5/libcustomwidget.so (Java_com_ak_customwidget_customwidget_CustomWidget_createCustomWidget+168)

02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a58  00000000  
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):          7ba93a5c  7ba93a20  [stack:22991]
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319): memory near r0:
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):     4432f598 00000000 0000001b 4201faa8 00000000  
02-01 14:48:51.692: I/DEBUG(319):     4432f5a8 00000000 4201f560 00000000 000000ab
```